# How to calculate the sum using pig script

Tags: apache-pig

Getting error while running the below command

    `Y = FOREACH X GENERATE ('entry1',(chararray)($0 matches '.*entry1.*'?  1:0)) as t1,('entry2',(chararray)($0 matches '.*entry2.*'?1:0)) as t2,('entry3',  (chararray)($0 matches '.*entry3.*'?1:0)) as t3,('entry4',(chararray)($0 matches   '.*entry4.*'?1:0)) as t4;`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: full code**

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE  FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(LOWER(line))) as word;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE ((word matches '.*entry1.*'? 1:0)) as t1,((word matches '.*entry2.*'?1:0)) as t2,((word matches '.*entry3.*'?1:0)) as t3,((word matches '.*entry4.*'?1:0)) as t4;
D = GROUP C ALL;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG(CONCAT('entry1',' ',(chararray)SUM(C.t1)),CONCAT('entry2',' ',(chararray)SUM(C.t2)),CONCAT('entry3',' ',(chararray)SUM(C.t3)),CONCAT('entry4',' ',(chararray)SUM(C.t4))));
DUMP E;
```

**Output:**

```
(entry1 2)
(entry2 0)
(entry3 2)
(entry4 1)
```

Comment: I tested it locally and its working fine for me.  Ok, can you paste  few lines of pig.txt input file?

Comment: I tried with your input data that you pasted and its working fine for me.Can you paste your complete pig script?